# iPhone - using the current Quartz context from a thread

Tags: iphone

I have a Quartz context declared in the main loop as

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mySize);
ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// bla bla bla
```

This context is changing, as the user is doing stuff on the screen.

At some point in the app I need a new thread to be fired and grab what the context has, saving to a UIImageView.

on the thread I have something like

```
myImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

but this is giving me nil, as the thread is not able to know that the current context is.

How do I solve that?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it may be a kludge but you could try this

```
- (void) myUIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext
    {
    myImageView.image= UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    }
```

Then in your thread replace the myImageView.Image=…line with this:

```
   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myUIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not changing anything. I am still receiving nil.

Comment: OK, I've re-posted the answer with something else you can try to determine if it is a threading related issue

Comment: Sorry, I'd have to see more code then to come up with any more ideas. If you want to post it I probably have time to look at it tonight